# Refering to an attribute of an object by another variable in R

Tags: r, variables, attributes

Is there any way to refer to the attributes of the objects by some other variable in R? The following example will explain, what I mean.

Let's say we have an object with some attributes - the kind of object is not important for the question. For example we can have

```
x <- 1:100
y <- x+rnorm(100)
obj <- lm(y~x+1)
```

Now I would like to write a function with an argument that would refer to one specific attribute of an object. For example, I would like to write a function, which would print values of some attributes of the created object. Specifically I want to have something like this:

```
fun <- function(obj, attr) {
          print(obj$attr)
       }
```

My question is, what is the way to refer to an attribute of an object by some other variable. I know that the example is silly, but I want to call attention to the problem, not to the function.

Thanks in advance

Kuba

Comment: *attributes* has a very specific meaning in R. To list the attributes of an object, do `attributes(obj)` and to get a specific attribute, do e.g. `attr(obj, "names")`. In your particular case, `obj` is a list (see `is.list(obj)`) and you are trying to extract its *elements* by name, not its *attributes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
fun <- function(obj, attr) {
          print(obj[[attr]])
       }
```

For example ,

```
fun(obj,'call')
lm(formula = y ~ x + 1)
```

Comment: Great!!! I haven't thought about the simplest solution. Thanks for the instant reply. And as I have already checked it works for my (a little bit more complicated) case it also works:)

Comment: or just `fun` <- `[[`, or better use `[[` directly!

Comment: I was wondering whether you could do the same with paste0(obj,"$",attr), but for some reason this doesn't work. I don't really see why, any tips? Thanks.

Comment: @MaximKovalenko Creating a string with the code you would want to evaluate shouldn't automatically evaluate it! That would be a disaster. agstudy provides the appropriate way to do what is being asked though and it sounds like the route you want to take will venture into using `eval` so I don't want to discuss that idea much more...